# Power BI URL filter parameter - Date filter

Tags: url, filter, powerbi

I am new to using filter parameters in the source URL for power BI queries.
I have successfully applied some fixed date filters, e.g. `?$filter = CURDATE ge 2022-01-01T00:00:00Z`.

Can someone please help me defining the correct filter parameters for CURDATE greater or equal to (today-90 days), i.e. the filter parameter equivalent to
">= Date.AddDays(DateTime.FixedLocalNow(),-90)"

I need to apply the data in the URL as the source data is huge and server performance is poor whilst I GET the data from the server. Applying the filter in the URL reduces the size of the GET command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If CURDATE is already configured as a date, you can simply go to Date Filters -> In the Previous:

[image]

And then define the period, for instance, previous 90 days:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Taisa - the issue I have is the data source is huge and server performance is poor whilst I GET the data from the server. Applying the filter in the URL reduces the size of the GET command.

Comment: Ah, ok! In this case you can: 
1) create a parameter in your Power Query for (-90 days)
2) create a little table containing the date parameter, and potentially all dates between your date parameter and today
3) transform the column to have the same string format as the one you have when using the GET command